# Using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs in Azure App Service .NET Backend

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-notificationhub

When configuring an Azure App Service backend you can choose between either a managed NodeJs project that works with EasyAuth and EasyTables or a full .NET based backend project that you can download and work with.

This project is based on an ASP.NET MVC template using .NET Framework 4.6.

When you want to integrate the Azure NotificationHub, you need to add nuget package references to Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs which target dotnetstandard2.0.

How can I either integrate the NotificationHub into my existing .NET backend project or migrate my .NET Framework 4.6 based backend project to dotnetstandard?

Answer (score 1):

d'oh.

As stated on Microsofts compatibility page, dotnetstandard2.0 requires .NET Framework 4.6.1. The template, an Azure App Service .NET Backend is based upon targets .NET Framework 4.6. So migrating this to 4.6.1 solved my problem.